# Colon in xml tag not able to be referenced in php

Tags: php, xml

I need something to either replace the colon, or find a way to work with it. This tag is inside of multiple other tags. This XML that is the problem:

```
<ns2:Amount>9.99</ns2:Amount>
```

This is the full xml

```
 <GetMatchingProductForIdResult Id="082686322638" IdType="UPC" status="Success">
<Products>
  <Product>
    <Identifiers>
      <MarketplaceASIN>
        <MarketplaceId>ATVPDKIKX0DER</MarketplaceId>
        <ASIN>B00TU53O8Q</ASIN>
      </MarketplaceASIN>
    </Identifiers>
    <AttributeSets>
      <ns2:ItemAttributes xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd" xml:lang="en-US">
        <ns2:Binding>Toy</ns2:Binding>
        <ns2:Brand>Rubie's</ns2:Brand>
        <ns2:Color>BLACK</ns2:Color>
        <ns2:Department>unisex-child</ns2:Department>
        <ns2:Feature>Half Helmet mask accessory covers face; one size fits most</ns2:Feature>
        <ns2:Feature>Officially licensed Star Wars Episode VII costume accessory; as worn by Kylo Ren in Star Wars Episode VII: The Force Awakens</ns2:Feature>
        <ns2:Feature>Helmet has faux battle damage representing a pivotal moment in the movie</ns2:Feature>
        <ns2:Feature>Kylo Ren costumes and additional accessories available separately</ns2:Feature>
        <ns2:Feature>Rubie's offers costumes and accessories from Star Wars original and prequel trilogies as well as the Clone Wars series; great group and family costume ideas</ns2:Feature>
        <ns2:ItemDimensions>
          <ns2:Height Units="inches">10.00</ns2:Height>
          <ns2:Length Units="inches">10.00</ns2:Length>
          <ns2:Width Units="inches">10.00</ns2:Width>
          <ns2:Weight Units="pounds">0.13</ns2:Weight>
        </ns2:ItemDimensions>
        <ns2:IsAdultProduct>false</ns2:IsAdultProduct>
        <ns2:Label>Rubies - Domestic</ns2:Label>
        <ns2:ListPrice>
          <ns2:Amount>9.99</ns2:Amount>
          <ns2:CurrencyCode>USD</ns2:CurrencyCode>
        </ns2:ListPrice>
        <ns2:Manufacturer>Rubies - Domestic</ns2:Manufacturer>
        <ns2:ManufacturerMaximumAge Units="months">120.0</ns2:ManufacturerMaximumAge>
        <ns2:ManufacturerMinimumAge Units="months">60.0</ns2:ManufacturerMinimumAge>
        <ns2:Model>32263</ns2:Model>
        <ns2:NumberOfItems>1</ns2:NumberOfItems>
        <ns2:PackageDimensions>
          <ns2:Height Units="inches">4.00</ns2:Height>
          <ns2:Length Units="inches">9.20</ns2:Length>
          <ns2:Width Units="inches">8.20</ns2:Width>
          <ns2:Weight Units="pounds">0.15</ns2:Weight>
        </ns2:PackageDimensions>
        <ns2:PackageQuantity>1</ns2:PackageQuantity>
        <ns2:PartNumber>32263</ns2:PartNumber>
        <ns2:ProductGroup>Toy</ns2:ProductGroup>
        <ns2:ProductTypeName>TOYS_AND_GAMES</ns2:ProductTypeName>
        <ns2:Publisher>Rubies - Domestic</ns2:Publisher>
        <ns2:Size>One Size</ns2:Size>
        <ns2:SmallImage>
          <ns2:URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41XuPVJMMkL._SL75_.jpg</ns2:URL>
          <ns2:Height Units="pixels">75</ns2:Height>
          <ns2:Width Units="pixels">66</ns2:Width>
        </ns2:SmallImage>
        <ns2:Studio>Rubies - Domestic</ns2:Studio>
        <ns2:Title>Star Wars: The Force Awakens Child's Kylo Ren Half Helmet</ns2:Title>
        <ns2:Warranty>No Warranty</ns2:Warranty>
      </ns2:ItemAttributes>
    </AttributeSets>
    <Relationships/>
    <SalesRankings>
      <SalesRank>
        <ProductCategoryId>toy_display_on_website</ProductCategoryId>
        <Rank>5183</Rank>
      </SalesRank>
      <SalesRank>
        <ProductCategoryId>2229575011</ProductCategoryId>
        <Rank>11</Rank>
      </SalesRank>
    </SalesRankings>
  </Product>
</Products>
</GetMatchingProductForIdResult>
```

I need to have `amount = 9.99` in PHP.

Comment: do you need Amount = 9.99 in php?

Comment: Yes. I just cannot figure out how to deal with the colon. Thanks! preferably using SimpleXML

Comment: You should post some example code ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  Include what you've already tried and where exactly you're stuck. See more info at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thanks!

Comment: @Robert: i have share a solution, check this

Comment: ns2 is a fallback/default prefix for a namespace (soap extensions use that), look for the xmlns:ns2 attribute for the actual namespace. You need to learn about namespaces and XML parsers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with basic PHP:

```
$subject = "<ns2:Amount>9.99</ns2:Amount>
<ns2:Test>ABCD</ns2:Test>"; // suppose you have two tags
preg_match_all('/<[^:]*:([^>]*)>(.*)<\/[^>]*>/', $subject, $matches); // matching

$i = 1;
$ii = 0;
foreach ($matches as $key => $value) {          
    $newArr[$matches[$i][$ii]] = $matches[$ii][$ii];            
    $ii++;
    $i++;
}

$result = array_filter($newArr); 
foreach($result as $key => $value){
  echo $key." = ".$value. "<br/>";
}
```

**Result is:**

```
Amount = 9.99
Test = ABCD
```

Comment: Interesting. I didn't think of it that way. If you look at the code i posted above, i was able to put it in 1 line. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Robert: this is good, now one last thing, chose the best answer and mark as accepted it will help for other who also facing same issue... by clicking the left green tick

Comment: This is not actually what i wanted. I need something that checks what the amount, size, ect are.

Comment: can you share your full XML? @Robert

Comment: Added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a code that let me ignore the namespaces. This is what it looks like.

```
$Amount = $xml->GetMatchingProductForIdResult[0]->Products->Product->AttributeSets->children('ns2', true)->ItemAttributes->Binding->Amount;
```